# How to optimize data aggregation in day of week, time of day for a period of one month back

Tags: mysql, graph, charts, aggregate

Here is the situation:

I have a SAAS Application which is a simple RSS Feed reader. I think most people know what this is - users subscribing to RSS feeds and then reading items from them. Nothing new. One feed can have many subscribers.

I've implemented some statistics for the users, but I don't think I've chosen the right approach, because things are getting slower by the hour as the number of users and feeds grows.

Here's what I'm doing now:

1. At every hour get the total number of articles for each feed:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles WHERE feed_id=?
   ```
2. Get the previous value to calculate the delta (this is getting a little slow):

   ```
   SELECT value FROM feeds_stats WHERE feed_id=? AND name='total_articles' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
   ```
3. Insert the new value and delta:

   ```
   INSERT INTO feeds_stats (date,feed_id,name,value,delta) VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$global_timestamp)."','".$feed_id','total_articles','".$value."','".($value-$old_value)."')
   ```
4. For every user get his feeds and for each feed get the number of articles he has read:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_articles ua JOIN articles a ON a.id=ua.article_id WHERE a.feed_id='%s' AND ua.user_id='%s' AND ua.read=1
   ```

users_articles is a table which holds the read state of each article per user

5. Then again get the delta:

   ```
   SELECT value FROM users_feeds_stats WHERE user_id='?' AND feed_id='?' AND name='total_reads' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
   ```
6. And insert the new value + delta:

   ```
   INSERT INTO users_feeds_stats (date,user_id,feed_id,name,value,delta) VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$global_timestamp)."','".$user_id."','".$feed_id."','total_reads','".$value."','".($value-$old_value)."')
   ```

**When all feeds for the user has been processed comes the aggregation part**:

This is a bit tricky and I think there should be a lot of room for optimization here.
Here is the actual aggregation function in PHP:

```
<?php

function aggregate_user_stats($user_id=false,$feed_id=false){
    global $global_timestamp;
    // defined dimensions
    $feed_types[0] = array("days_back" => 31, "group_by" => "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')");
    $feed_types[1] = array("days_back" => 31, "group_by" => "WEEKDAY(date)+1");
    $feed_types[2] = array("days_back" => 31, "group_by" => "HOUR(date)");

    if($user_id){
        $where = " WHERE id=".$user_id;
    }

    $feed_where = "";
    $getusers = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users".$where)or die(__LINE__." ".mysql_error());
    while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($getusers)){
        if($feed_id){
            $feed_where = " AND feed_id=".$feed_id;
        }

        $user_feeds = array();
        $getfeeds = mysql_query("SELECT feed_id FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id='".$user["id"]."' AND active=1".$feed_where)or die(__LINE__." ".mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfeeds)){
            foreach($feed_types as $tab => $type){
                $getdata = mysql_query("
                SELECT ".$type["group_by"]." AS date, name, SUM(delta) AS delta FROM feeds_stats WHERE feed_id = '".$row["feed_id"]."' AND name='total_articles' AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$type["days_back"]." DAY) GROUP BY name, ".$type["group_by"]." 
                UNION 
                SELECT ".$type["group_by"]." AS date, name, SUM(delta) AS delta FROM users_feeds_stats WHERE user_id = '".$user["id"]."' AND feed_id = '".$row["feed_id"]."' AND name='total_reads' AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$type["days_back"]." DAY) GROUP BY name, ".$type["group_by"]."
                ")or die(__LINE__." ".mysql_error());
                $data = array();
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata)){
                    $data[$row["date"]][$row["name"]] = $row["delta"];
                }
                if(count($data)){
                    db_start_trx();
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM stats_feeds_over_time WHERE feed_id='".$row["feed_id"]."' AND user_id='".$user["id"]."' AND tab='".$tab."'")or die(__LINE__." ".mysql_error());
                    foreach($data as $time => $keys){
                        mysql_query("REPLACE INTO stats_feeds_over_time (feed_id,user_id,tab,date,total_articles,total_reads,total_favs) VALUES ('".$row["feed_id"]."','".$user["id"]."','".$tab."','".$time."','".$keys["total_articles"]."','".$keys["total_reads"]."','".$keys["total_favs"]."')")or die(__LINE__." ".mysql_error());
                    }
                    db_commit_trx();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

Edit: Here are the DDL's of the involved tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(1000) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` VARCHAR(2000) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author` VARCHAR(200) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hash` CHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `feed_id_hash` (`feed_id`, `hash`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `url` (`url`(255))
)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT='';


CREATE TABLE `users_articles` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `article_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subscription_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `read` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`, `article_id`),
  KEY `article_id` (`article_id`),
  KEY `subscription_id` (`subscription_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
CHECKSUM=1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT='';


CREATE TABLE `feeds_stats` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  `delta` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT='';


CREATE TABLE `users_feeds_stats` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `feed_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  `delta` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT='';

CREATE TABLE `stats_feeds_over_time` (
  `feed_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  `tab` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `total_articles` DOUBLE(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `total_reads` DOUBLE(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `total_favs` DOUBLE(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feed_id`, `user_id`, `tab`, `date`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT='';
```

In the end of the aggregation function there is a REPLACE in table stats_feeds_over_time. This table holds just the records, that will be displayed on the graph, so the actual graphing process does not involve heavy queries.

Finally here are the graphs produced by this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would be glad if someone point me in the right direction on where and how to optimize this solution, even if it means to ditch MySQL for statistics.

I have long experience with [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/), but here the situation is different, because of the "Time of day", "Day of week" aggregations.

Comment: what's the db schema for the involved tables?

Comment: what indexes are you using?

Comment: I've added the DDLs in the Edit

Comment: in `articles` what's the `hash` column for?

Comment: It's used to store a unique hash of the article, so when new articles arrive, they are checked against this hash to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how important are the queries you wish to optimize with regard to the other queries you might run on the same set of tables. I will assume that you wish first to have these queries optimized.

Seeing that all the queries are made with `feed_id` as `WHERE` predicates, I would try to partition the `articles` table on that column:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  -- etc.
)ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=0
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
COMMENT=''
PARTITION BY KEY(feed_id)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

The number of partitions (`10` above) can be tuned according to your needs, yet must be above 1 to have any impact. You might want to use a larger number to make your select queries faster. However any query non dependent on `feed_id` will be slowered by this device.

The same process can be applied to other tables with columns often used as discriminant in queries.

However, as your first two queries are executed for all the feeds, you could rewrite them as follow:

```
SELECT feed_id, COUNT(feed_id) 
FROM articles
GROUP BY feed_id

SELECT feed_id, value
FROM feeds_stats
WHERE name='total_articles' 
GROUP BY feed_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Both these would retrieve the results for all the feeds, which frees you from having to run the queries for each individual feed. Using these queries makes the partitioning counter productive, so you will have to choose between the two.

The good point of partitioning: any query discriminating against one particular value of `feed_id` (or any other column used for partition) will see a significant boost. The bad point is that regular queries will be slowed down.

The good point of the second solution is that it will not have any impact on other queries.

Comment: I will try the second solution, because partitioning might slow down the core part of the application. I can sacrifice statistics until I find a solution :)